# Issue while Getting message count from MSMQ Outqueue

Tags: c#, powershell, msmq

I'm trying to get the count of messages present in outgoing queue. I'm using C# with Powershell to achieve this.
I'm using below command

```
Get-MsmqOutgoingQueue | Format-Table -Property MessageCount
```

This command is getting executed successfully on powershell command prompt. But when I try this from C#, it is giving following exception:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.Utilities' threw an exception.
```

Below is the C# code that I'm using to execute this command:

```
string scriptTest = "Get-MsmqOutgoingQueue | Format-Table -Property MessageCount";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
string s = "";
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
   s = obj.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I tried this code by giving all permission but it's giving same exception.

Comment: Is there an InnerException?

Comment: Checked InnerException and found exception as :"Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information" Fixed it by modifying App.Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding following useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy in Startup tag.

```
<configuration>
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
 </startup>
</configuration>
```